# Send ID for transaction inside smart contract can not be _self

Tags: transactions, bug

With the last CDT, to send transaction inside smart contract, here is my code

```
  eosio::transaction out;
  out.actions.emplace_back(eosio::permission_level{get_self(), "active"_n}, get_self(), "profilesum"_n, packed_data);
  out.delay_sec = 0;
  out.send( _self, _self,true);
```

When i compile with cdt. the error shows at below

> error: no viable conversion from 'eosio::name' to 'const uint128_t'
>         (aka 'const unsigned __int128')   out.send( _self, _self,true);

Here is send() function, we need input sender_id with data type uint128_t. But what is sender_id? when i tried to build with old version, evething work fine with above code. Anyone know the reason?

> ```
>  void send(const uint128_t& sender_id, account_name payer, bool replace_existing = false) const {
>      auto serialize = pack(*this);
>      send_deferred(sender_id, payer, serialize.data(), serialize.size(), replace_existing);
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I know 1.4.4 broke some things like removing types.hpp from the basic eosio.hpp import, so I would recommend getting on 1.5.

Here is an example of a spamming action that you may be able to compare and see what's different | [code link](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/blob/dec-2018-workshop/examples/messenger/messenger.cpp):

```
    [[eosio::action]]
   void spam( name from, name to, uint64_t msg_id, const string& msg_str, uint32_t delay_sec ) {
      require_auth( from );

      if( msg_id > 10 )
         return;

      {
         eosio::transaction out;
         out.actions.emplace_back( eosio::permission_level{_self, "active"_n}, to, "sendmsg"_n,
                                   std::make_tuple( from, to, ++msg_id, msg_str ));
         out.delay_sec = delay_sec;
         out.send( msg_id, _self );
      }
      {
         eosio::transaction out;
         out.actions.emplace_back( eosio::permission_level{_self, "active"_n}, _self, "spam"_n,
                                   std::make_tuple( from, to, ++msg_id, msg_str, delay_sec ));
         out.delay_sec = delay_sec;
         out.send( msg_id, _self );
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The sender ID is expecting a 128-bit integer, but you are providing an instance of the `name` class. In order to access the integer version of this, you must type `_self.value`.

Disclaimer: I haven't test this yet